# Opening password-protected pdf file with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, passwords, itext

I'm making an application that should display PDFs with password. This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = Request.QueryString["filePath"];
            if (filePath.ToUpper().EndsWith("PDF"))
            {
                copyPDF(filePath);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            string message = "<script language='Javascript'>alert('File Not Found! Call Records Department for verification. ')</script>";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), message, message, false);
        }
    }
}
public void copyPDF(string filePath)
{
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray ra = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(Server.MapPath(ResolveUrl(filePath)));
    if (ra != null)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        byte[] password = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Secretinfo");
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader thepdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(ra, password);
        int pages = thepdfReader.NumberOfPages;
        iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy pdfCopy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(pdfDoc, ms);

        pdfDoc.Open();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < pages)
        {
            pdfCopy.AddPage(pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(thepdfReader, i + 1));
            i += 1;
        }
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Byte[] byteInfo = ms.ToArray();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", byteInfo.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(byteInfo);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

My code has no problem opening pdf files without password but it can't open pdfs with password even though the password is supplied. The application executes the catch instead. What seems to be wrong with my code?

**EDIT**:
I removed the *Catch* to see the exception thrown.

> **Exception Details**: System.ArgumentException: PdfReader not opened with owner password

It says the source of the error is Line 51.

```
Line 49:    while (i < pages)
Line 50:    {
Line 51:         pdfCopy.AddPage(pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(thepdfReader, i + 1));
Line 52:         i += 1;
Line 53:    }
```

Comment: Which exception is thrown?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception. It executes the catch statement which in this case is a popup that says 'File Not Found! Call Records Department for verification.'

Comment: hey @mkl I removed the Catch to find out what kind of exception is thrown It says **System.ArgumentException: PdfReader not opened with owner password**.

Comment: It seems that you haven't provided the correct password.

Comment: I did. I checked. Like 10 times. Maybe I need to supply the password again somewhere along Line 51?

Comment: Maybe the PDF both has a user and an owner password and you provided the user password only.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For certain operations on encrypted documents iText(Sharp) requires that the document not merely is opened with the user password but instead with the owner password. This corresponds to the definition of these passwords in the PDF specification:

> Whether additional operations shall be allowed on a decrypted document depends on which password (if any) was supplied when the document was opened and on any access restrictions that were specified when the document was created:
>
> - Opening the document with the correct *owner* password should allow full (owner) access to the document. This unlimited access includes the ability to change the document’s passwords and access permissions.
> - Opening the document with the correct *user* password (or opening a document with the default password) should allow additional operations to be performed according to the user access permissions specified in the document’s encryption dictionary.
>
> *(section 7.6.3.1 in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

iText(Sharp) currently does not check in detail *the user access permissions specified in the document’s encryption dictionary* but instead always requires the owner password for operations requiring certain permissions, and copying whole pages from a document definitively is one of them.

This been said, the iText(Sharp) developers are very much aware (due to many such questions asked)

- that iText(Sharp) users may be entitled to execute such operations even without the owner password on account of the before mentioned *user access permissions specified in the document’s encryption dictionary,*
- that there are myriad PDFs to which their respective owners applied an owner password (to prevent misuse by others) and then forgot it (or by using a randomly generated one never knew it to start with), and
- that iText(Sharp) (being open source) can easily be patched by anyone not to respect the differences between user and owner password.

To allow users to do what they are entitled to and to prevent the spreading of patched copies of the library, iText(Sharp) contains an override for this test in the `PdfReader` class:

```
/**
 * The iText developers are not responsible if you decide to change the
 * value of this static parameter.
 * @since 5.0.2
 */
public static bool unethicalreading = false;
```

Thus, by setting

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

you globally override this permission checking mechanism.

**Please respect the rights of PDF authors and only use this override if you indeed are entitled to execute the operations in question.**

Comment: I used this and now I'm getting an **InvalidCastException** error _Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference'._

Comment: Then either your PDF or itext had an error. Can you provide the PDF for analysis?

Comment: How can I provide you the PDF? (Sorry. If you tell me how I can do that I'll be more than happy to.)

Comment: Stackoverflow itself does not have a service for file exchange. Thus, when in the context of Stackoverflow files are to be provided, often some file sharing service is used, e.g. making the files available via Dropbox or google drive, and the URL is posted here.

Comment: you can see the PDF [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3NSgBUZBzelOHhsNnY0dHc2VTg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The document does not seem to be available publicly. Google Drive tells me "You need permission."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33680/discussion-between-artemis-and-mkl)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this workaround to unlock protected PdfReader. It's work for me:

```
public static PdfReader TryToUnlockPdf(PdfReader reader)
{
    if (reader == null)
    {
        return reader;
    }
    try
    {
        var f = reader.GetType().GetField("encrypted", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        f?.SetValue(reader, false);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { // ignore
    }
    return reader;
}

private static void GetPdfPageFiles(this Page pageFile)
{
    reader = new PdfReader(pageFile.ContentBytes);
    // Unlock protected 
    reader = TryToUnlockPdf(reader);

    // if no using TryToUnlockPdf workaroud - GetImportedPage method raises "System.ArgumentException: PdfReader not opened with owner password"
    var curPage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(reader, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I applied this workaround and it works:

```
private void fixIssue(PdfReader pdfReader) throws Exception {
        Field f = pdfReader.getClass().getDeclaredField("ownerPasswordUsed");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.setBoolean(pdfReader, true);

}
```

Comment: While I know that there are some occasions in which one has to use reflection for interesting effects in iText, there is no need for that here.

Comment: Well it's just a workaround, as I wrote. But it works :) Probably it makes more sense to use one of the provided constructors in order to set ownerPasswordUsed to true. http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.java

Comment: @mkl There IS a need for it.  I use the old iTextSharp 4.x to avoid commercial licensing, which has no easy way to set that field.

Comment: @ChrisBordeman Ok, so there is no need for that *in the context of the question* as the OP apparently uses a newer version of iText. For iText versions before 5.0.2 reflection indeed is the only solution if one does not want to patch the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfReader.AllowOpenWithFullPermissions = true;

pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
```

Comment: You might want to mention that the `PdfReader.AllowOpenWithFullPermissions` flag is specific to the `iTextSharp.LGPLv2` fork. The original iTextSharp uses the `PdfReader.unethicalreading` flag.