# how to show password protected pdf file in browser in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my application which is in asp.net 4.0 we are uploading password protected pdf files on server for course material. when user will login i want to show those password protected pdf files in browser. and when user will download pdf it should ask for password.

Can any one suggest the solution, how i can achieve this without using any third party tool.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this links.... they will help u...

[Opening password-protected pdf file with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666577/opening-password-protected-pdf-file-with-itextsharp)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1573630.aspx

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/286175

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc0bf025-4751-4f81-bb34-81497a9bfbdf/how-to-open-a-secured-password-protected-pdf-file-progrmatically-in-aspnet-using-c?forum=Offtopic

Comment: i don`t want to manipulate file, can i do this without manipulating file.

Comment: Do one thing that while storing up at your website store it with password. At the time of display on web provide password to it through code-behind. So now whenever user download that file. He/she will get that pdf with password.

Comment: thanks for the reply but can you suggest me any example for the same as i have searched lot but did not find right solution.

Comment: ok.... actully i had never done this before. But will try it and provide u solution asap.

Comment: hey @rahul.deshmukh you must have to use third party tool. Otherwise it will not gonna work...