# How to add annotations and highlights to an encrypted PDF file?

Tags: c#, java, pdf, pdfclown

I need to write an application, which highlights some text in a PDF file and add annotations to them.

I've used the PDF Clown library and it works well with non-encrypted files in the following way:

1. I read the PDF file A.
2. Add some annotations and highlights.
3. Write out the result to PDF file B.

File A is not changed.

This works well for non-encryped files, but does not work for encrypted ones.

How can I add highlights and annotations to an encrypted file in C# or Java?

Comment: did u try itextpdf with batik?

Comment: No, I didn't try it yet. Does it support highlights and annotations in encrypted PDF files?

Comment: i guess so, is this what u want? http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=219

Comment: Not really. The problem is - I don't have the password of the PDF I want to add highlights to.

Comment: Are you allowed to do those changes? Encryption of PDF often is done to disallow certain operations on a PDF. If you are allowed, have a look at [this answer to "Opening password-protected pdf file with iTextSharp"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666577/opening-password-protected-pdf-file-with-itextsharp/17694943#17694943).

Comment: @mkl I'm writing a tool for highlighting the text in PDF files for a client. There is one bug, which occurs in files of the client. He told me that I can use any Nikon camera user manual for testing. After your comment, I tried to highlight and annotate those manuals (downloaded from the official Nikon web site) and found out that I can't do that even in Acrobat Reader. So the problem is probably not with my code, but with the files being protected. I didn't know that you can't highlight and annotate protected files. I requested nonencrypted files from the client for testing.Thx for your hint!