# Extract pages from certificated pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, certificate, itext

I am trying to extract page from PDF with certificate in c# with iTextSharp. Important info that I **don't have password**. I tried using PDFCopy, but it throws exception when tried to extract page (source code below).

Exception message is: PdfReader not opened with owner password. It cause this section of code: `importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);`

Actual state: My solution extract pages of PDFs without certificate.

State I want: Solution is able to work with PDF with certificate.

My answer is: **Is it possible to extract page from certificated pdf without password, how?**

Solution: Setting property (unethicalreading) of PdfReader to true so it 
ignores the password but invalidate the certificate. 
`PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;`

Actual Code:

```
public void ExtractPdfPages(string sourcePdfPath, string outputPdfPath, int numberOfPage)
{
  PdfReader reader = null;
  Document sourceDocument = null;
  PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
  PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;
  int pageCount;
  try
  {


    using (reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath))
    {
      pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
      sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
      pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument,
          new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

      sourceDocument.Open();

      int actualPageCount = pageCount > numberOfPage ? numberOfPage : pageCount;

      for (int i = 1; i <= actualPageCount; i++)
      {
        importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
        pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
      }

      sourceDocument.Close();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);        
  }
}
```

Comment: What is, in PDF terms, a certificated PDF? Are you referring to a PDF that is *encrypted* using a public certificate (**certificate encryption**)? Or are you referring to a PDF that has an *author signature* applied using a private key (**certification signature**). If the former, you need the private key that corresponds with the public certificate to achieve what you want; if the latter, there shouldn't be any problem, except that the signature won't survive the operation (what is to be expected because extracting a page invalidates the signature).

Comment: Sorry, forgon mention that.. It has an author signature..

Comment: @BrunoLowagie So it is impossible to extract pages and without invalidate signature?

Comment: An author signature cannot be the cause of a "PdfReader not opened with owner password" exception because a signature has nothing to do with passwords.(Unless the exception is completely misleading, obviously...)

Comment: *"So it is impossible to extract pages and without invalidate signature"* - yes, PDF signatures aren't page-wise but revision-wise.

Comment: As far as I remember, the PdfReader has a Property that can be set to ignore the password. - Nope it was a method: public PdfReader setUnethicalReading(boolean unethicalReading) But if you change the original file, signatures will be broken anyway. That's what they are there for.

Comment: @mkl You was right, my information was incorrect. The document is certificated under 40bit RC4 crypto. I'll update question. Is there any way to achieve the goal I want?

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for comment I am going to look for that. :)

Comment: @Fildor You've been directing me right way. I am using iText v. 4.5.5. so it has only property `PdfReader.unethicalreading`. Please create an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: *"The document is certificated under 40bit RC4 crypto."* - If by "certificated" you mean "encrypted", all you have to do is follow @Fildor's comment and set the static `PdfReader.unethicalreading` variable to `true`. In that case your question effectively duplicates [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17694943/1729265).

Comment: There is no iText 4.5.5. Any iText 4 version is *not* the official iText. Please throw that version away, and use an *official* version.

Comment: Followed. You are right, if you can mark as duplicate, please do it.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie 5.5.9.. my bad.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie *"Any iText 4 version is not the official iText."* - This is about iTextSharp / iText for .Net, and in that context there indeed were official 4.x versions (in parallel to the iText for Java  2.x versions). There were no official 4.5.x versions, though.

Comment: Indeed, @mkl I overlooked the fact that C# code was used.